# Convert clustered LVM volume group to stand alone

Tags: virtual-machines, lvm, cluster

I am running clustered LVM, and I need to convert my cLVM VGs back to stand alone. It appears that I should be able to run "vgchange -c n " with out losing any LVs. The only thing I need to do is temporarily disable locking (locking_type = 0).

Is this "safe?" I am being very cautious because I have a lot of VMs on these VGs :)

Thanks!

--Will

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In lvm.conf, change locking_type=3 to 1 instead of 0. if you change 0. then volume group may be corrupt.